# Android Sliding Tabs using custom XML files

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Does anyone know of any sample Sliding Tabs projects where custom XML files have been used? By custom XML I mean where the pages have data that the user has put in rather than pushing data. I want to create a sliding tabs project where I can use my own XML files to present my own pages of text rather than pushing data. I've looked all over the internet but can't find anything relevant.

Comment: Not clear what exactly you are trying to ask. What do you mean by putting and pushing data??

Comment: Basically the page that the user flicks to scroll from page to page, I want to use my own xml files rather than data being pushed on one page (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.)

Comment: No, I don't want a sliding menu. I want sliding tabs just like in this image: [Music store screenshot](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/steps.jpg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a separate fragment file for each tab, using a Tabhost as a container, I made it recently following this post, there should be many others out there:

http://android.codeandmagic.org/android-tabs-with-fragments/

I attach below some code for the approach I think you-re trying to make, with some code I made recently:

**XML**:

*Pager Container:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:padding="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_width=
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:background="@color/teal_cover"
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/pagerr"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                 />
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>


</TabHost>
```

*Tab 1:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    //.... Rest of XML..............///////////////

    </ScrollView>
```

*Tab 2:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container_list_item"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/warning_li"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java:

Container.

```
package com.ciudad2020.medioambiente2020;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Search extends ActionBarActivity implements
    TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

private FragmentPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private TabHost mTabHost;
private ViewPager mPager;
private HashMap<String, TabInfo> mapTabInfo = new HashMap<String, Search.TabInfo>();
public User us;
private int page;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // View v=findViewById(R.layout.pager);







    Log.e("Tipo de usuario", AppManager.getInstance().getUser().getUserType());
    Log.e("ESNULL",Boolean.toString(AppManager.getInstance().getSharedPreferences(AppManager.getInstance().getUser().getId(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)==null));


    setContentView(R.layout.pager);
    us = AppManager.getInstance().getUser();

    this.initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
    }
    // Intialise ViewPager
    this.intialiseViewPager();

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    page = intent.getIntExtra("page", 0);

    this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(page);
    this.mPager.setCurrentItem(page);


    for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);


        TextView tv = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }

    // args.putString("id", id);;
    // us.loadFromDb();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
    Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(setIntent);
}



protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); // save the tab
                                                            // selected
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

/**
 * Initialise ViewPager
 */
private void intialiseViewPager() {

    if (us.getUserType().equals("REGISTERED")) {

    this.mAdapter = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager());
    //
    }

    else{

        this.mAdapter = new ViewerPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager());

    }

    this.mPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pagerr);
    this.mPager.setPageMargin(20);
    this.mPager.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    this.mPager.setAdapter(this.mAdapter);
    this.mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}

private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {

    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    TabInfo tabInfo;

    Search.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1")
            .setIndicator("Información"), (tabInfo = new TabInfo(
            "Tab1", InfoFragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);

    Search.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3")
            .setIndicator("Alertas"), (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab3",
            WarningsFragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);


    // Default to first tab
    // this.onTabChanged("Tab1");
    //
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}

/**
 * Add Tab content to the Tabhost
 * 
 * @param activity
 * @param tabHost
 * @param tabSpec
 */
private static void AddTab(Search activity, TabHost tabHost,
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
    // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec
    tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}

public void muestraTostada(String cartel) {
    Toast.makeText(this, cartel, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


public static class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {

        return (1f);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        InfoFragment iF = new InfoFragment();
        WarningsFragment wF = new WarningsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("number", position);

        switch (position) {
        case 0:

            return iF;
        case 1:
            return wF;

        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public static class ViewerPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ViewerPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {

        return (1f);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        InfoFragment iF = new InfoFragment();
        WarningsFragment wF = new WarningsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("number", position);

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return iF;

        case 1:
            return wF;

        case 2:
                return wF;

        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    int pos = this.mPager.getCurrentItem();
    this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(pos);

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {


}

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
    int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    this.mPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
}

/**
 * 
 * @author cbg Maintains extrinsic info of a tab's construct
 */

private class TabInfo {
    private String tag;
    private Class<?> clss;
    private Bundle args;
    private Fragment fragment;

    TabInfo(String tag, Class<?> clazz, Bundle args) {
        this.tag = tag;
        this.clss = clazz;
        this.args = args;
    }
}

class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

    private final Context mContext;

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    public TabFactory(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory#createTabContent(java.lang.String)
     */
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        View v = new View(mContext);
        v.setMinimumWidth(0);
        v.setMinimumHeight(0);
        return v;
    }

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {

        case R.id.action_edit:
            showEditDialog();

            // Toast.makeText(this, "home pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        case R.id.action_warnings:
            showEditWarningsDialog();

    }

    return true;
}

public void showEditDialog() {


    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    EditDialog editNameDialog = new EditDialog();
    editNameDialog.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
}


public void showEditWarningsDialog(){

    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    EditWarningsDialog editWarningsDialog = new EditWarningsDialog();
    editWarningsDialog.show(fm, "fragment_edit_warning");


}


}
```

Rest fragment classes are not relevant, just take a look on the container part.

The result is something like attached below, I guess for what you've said is sth like you're looking for.

Hope it helps. Cheers.

[image: Result]

Comment: You're on the right track, but I want it to look like the sliding tabs seen in the Google Play Store just like this one: [Music store screenshot](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/steps.jpg)

Comment: Create you own fragment as required.

Comment: I know that I need to create fragments of my own, but it's the code/sample project (if any) that I'm after.

Comment: That's it kind of what I'm looking for but I want it in the form of Sliding Tabs just like the one in this link: [sliding tabs screenshot](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/steps.jpg)

Comment: This one make the same approach, they're sliding tabs, making the same behaviour than attached.If more tabs were needed just need to add it in the container class.